# Detect and install a device which has been removed by pnputil /remove-device

Tags: batch-file, cmd

While trying to figure out, how to totally deactive the USB Ports temporarily, I stumbled across the command pnputil /remove-device <Instance-ID>

Although it now is deactivated, I can't figure out how the computer could redetect and install the device!

Up to now I tried:

Restarting the computer

pnputil /scan-devices

Searching for devices in the Device Manager

I would be glad if you could help me out!

Comment: Why remove a device if you wanted to not remove it? The purpose of this exercise was? Just install the driver using `pnputil`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.